# Pyqtgraph RemoteGraphicsView and connecting signals

Tags: proxy, pyqt, pyqtgraph

So I'm currently using a RemoteGraphicsView in my application and I have included a LinearRegionItem
into the view. I'm trying to connect the signal "sigRegionChanged" to a function in my application but I am getting the following errors depending on what I try.

New Style Signal/Slot

```
my_region.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.my_function)
```

I get the following error that comes from the handler calls

> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup builtins.method failed

Old style

```
self.connect(spot_area, QtCore.SIGNAL('sigRegionChanged'), self.spot_adjusted)
```

Gets an error about the spot_area being an ObjectProxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because you are trying to send your callback function directly to the remote process, and pickle does not know how to serialize a function. Instead, you need to manually create a *proxy* to your callback and send that instead:

```
proxy = pg.multiprocess.proxy(self.my_function, callSync='off', autoProxy=True) 
myRegion.sigRegionChanged.connect(proxy)
```

There are some other subtleties here:

- The `callSync` argument improves performance by telling the remote process that, when it invokes the callback, it should *not* wait for a return value.
- The `autoProxy` argument is needed because when the remote process invokes the callback, it will attempt to send the `LinearRegionItem` as an argument (since this is the first argument to the signal). Using `autoProxy=True` instructs the remote process to send it by proxy rather than attempting to pickle it (which would fail).

Comment: Thank you! I will try this shortly. So the autoProxy is one of the keys I guess. I had tried to do the multiprocess proxy before and I received the same error. For my education and curiosity sake is there a reason that methods aren't already excluded?

Comment: I can't think of a good reason. Probably `autoProxy` should be enabled by default..